# Prefixing string value to IBOutlet and INT variable names

Tags: objective-c, xcode, string, iboutlet

I have a number of IBOutlets which are prefixed with 'playerOne' 'playerTwo' etc.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *playerOneTurnButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *playerTwoTurnButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *playerOneChallengeButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *playerTwoChallengeButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *playerOneTimeLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *playerTwoTimeLabel;
```

And I have some declared some variables which are also prefixed with 'playerOne' 'playerTwo' etc...

```
int playerOneTimeRemaining;
int playerTwoTimeRemaining;
int playerThreeTimeRemaining;

etc ...
```

At various points I'd like to manipulate these outlets (adjusting the alpha, hidden and active properties) dependent on who's turn it is and I also need to change the int value of some of the variables.
I have various `NSStrings` (the one in this example is called `whoWasChallengedFromGame`) which keeps track of who's go it is. `@"playerOne"` or `@playerTwo"` etc for each player.

At the moment I have an if statement which checks the string and performs a block of code. This block of code is pretty much the same each time just the names of the outlets and variables are adjusted each time...

```
-(void)challengeAccepted {
Store *myStore = [Store sharedStore];
if (([myStore.whoWasChallengedFromGame isEqual:@"playerOne"]) && ([myStore.brutalModeFromOptions isEqual:@"lenient"])) {
    playerOneTimeRemaining -= 30;
    playerOneTimeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", playerOneTimeRemaining];
}

if (([myStore.whoWasChallengedFromGame isEqual:@"playerTwo"]) && ([myStore.brutalModeFromOptions isEqual:@"lenient"])) {
    playerTwoTimeRemaining -= 30;
    playerTwoTimeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", playerTwoTimeRemaining];

}

etc etc for each player
```

As you can see as the amount of players increases this is really not going to be manageable.
What i'm looking to do is to able to write a single block of code that will check the string `whoWasChallengedFromGame` and prefix the `IBOutlet` and variable names

so the code will then simply have to say

```
"string"TimeRemaining -=30
"string"TimeLabel.text= blah blah
```

and the code will simply translate the "string" part into playerOne or playerTwo or whatever is in the string `whoWasChallengedFromGame`.

Any ideas if this can be done?

Comment: It might be more appropriate to make a clas `Player`, that way you can create as many as you need.

Comment: Also might be more appropriate to use `typedef enum`s for the settings rather than NSStrings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `PlayerControls` class, initialize it in the `viewDidLoad` for each player in the game, and then use `PlayerControls` for the current player to do the adjustments.

Here is a quick example:

```
@interface PlayerControls : NSObject
@property (weak, nonatomic) UIButton *turnButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) UIButton *challengeButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) UILabel *timeLabel;
@end
```

Create per-player instances of the `PlayerControls`, and put them into an array. Add this declaration to your controller:

```
PlayerControls *playerControls[2];

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    playerControls[0] = [[PlayerControls alloc] init];
    playerControls[0].turnButton = self.playerOneTurnButton;
    playerControls[0].challengeButton = self.playerOneChallengeButton;
    playerControls[0].timeLabel = self.playerOneTimeLabel;
    playerControls[1] = [[PlayerControls alloc] init];
    playerControls[1].turnButton = self.playerTwoTurnButton;
    playerControls[1].challengeButton = self.playerTwoChallengeButton;
    playerControls[1].timeLabel = self.playerTwoTimeLabel;
}
```

From this point on, you can refer to the current player by its index: zero for player one, one for player two. You can add more players as needed, without changing the code.

Comment: Ok.I like the idea of a class if only to make things a bit more manageable in terms of the structure. Keeping things separate etc. I think I'll start looking into using a player class to start with and see how we go.

Comment: @user2097662 The key idea, though, is the use of the array; the class is simply a mean to that end. Keeping things separate is a nice byproduct, it's the ability to use an array index instead of prefixing the name in a lots of `if`s or copy/pasted code fragments that you get by taking this approach.

Comment: Arrays were definitely the way forward for me. The above question is a bit mute now as since I've started using arrays my original code no longer applies. However since the suggestion to start using arrays was the key for me I think you deserve to be marked as the answer. Thanks very much everyone

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to achieve what you're after using [Key-Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html) (KVC).

In particular, take a look at [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/BasicPrinciples.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002170-BAJEAIEE).  In order to incorporate your player information, you could do something like:

```
[myInstance setValue:someAppropriateValue
              forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@challengeButton", currentPlayer]];
```

However, I would probably do this using a class.  I would strongly recommend that you use a wrapper class to manage the players, though, so something like:

```
@interface PlayerStates

- (UIButton *)turnButtonForPlayer:(NSInteger)player
...etc

@end
```

The disadvantage of this approach is that you can't use `IBOutlet`s directly (although you could build it from an `IBOutletCollection`).

If you do need to use an `IBOutlet` for each widget, I'd probably do it using KVC, but make sure to use named constants for your players:

```
typedef enum {
    PlayerOne,
    PlayerTwo,
} Player;

@property (nonatomic) Player currentPlayer;
```

And then get the string you need for KVC using:

```
- (NSString *)stringForPlayer:(Player)player
{
    switch (player) {
        case PlayerOne:
            return @"playerOne";
        ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Sapi, I think given my currently low level of knowledge I'm going to attempt to use a playerClass of some sort with an array as the KVC stuff scares me at the moment. However This is all part of a wide learning process for me so I'll try some use of KVC in the future.